# How to stop an image from expanding my flex container while keeping the Image aspect ratio?

Tags: css, image, flexbox, grid

So no matter what image I try to use when placing it in the flex container `head-top-right`, it expands my flex container while distorting the image next to it and also expands the outer flex container. How do I place any image while also not expanding the flex item the image is in and also distorting the images next to it. I have `max-height:100%;` but it's not helping and I assume that it's because the parent container does not have a height set. Is that a possibility?

```css
.head {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 38px 40px;
}

.head-top {
  display: flex;
}

.head-search {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.search-img {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.head-top-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.head-profile-pic {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="head-top">
    <img src="pic/magnify.png" class="search-img">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="head-search" />
    <div class="head-top-right">
      <img src="pic/notifications.png">
      <img src="pic/earth.jpg" class="head-profile-pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```